# Simple d3.js bar chart is inverted when I add in .text()

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a very simple d3.js bar chart that looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/9/

However, as soon as I take out the

```
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

it's fine!

http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/10/

Does anyone know why the first case (where I have text from the data list populating in the markup) is inverted? Do I need to set orientation of the axis somewhere?

Comment: It is because of the way `display: inline-block` behaves depending on whether there is text present. If you specify `vertical-align: top`, the different default behavior is overriden and they will behave the same. Google for `display: inline-block` and you will find several posts describing the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right it with `vertical-align: bottom` per FernOfTheAndes' comment.

http://jsfiddle.net/jTs9A/26/